# Set range of axis in plotly R with type mesh3d

Tags: r, 3d, range, axis, plotly

I am using Rstudio on a mac.
I want to 3dplot a surface thanks to 4 points with their cartesian coordinates.
When I use : plot_ly(x=x, y=y) I am able to fix the range of the axis.
When using plot_ly(x=x, y=y, z=z) the same method of ranging the axis does not work anymore.

```
x = c(0, 1, 1, 0)
y = c(0, 0, 1, 1)
z = c(0, 1, 1, 0)
scene = list(camera = list(eye = list(x=-2.5, y=0.1, z=0.1), center=list(x=0, y=0, z=0), up=list(x=0, y=0, z=1)))
axx <- list(range=c(0, 10), showline=TRUE, linecolor=toRGB("black"))
p <- plot_ly(x = x, y = y, z = z, text = c("M0", "M1", "M2", "M3"),
            type = "mesh3d",
            showscale = FALSE
      ) %>%
    layout(scene=scene, xaxis=axx,  yaxis=axx, zaxis=axx )
```

In fine I intend to use this code to be looped on a data.frame and see the evolution of my point. And there is no point on doing that if I cannot have the same scale on each plot iteration.

```
for (ind in 1:datalen)
{
  print(ind)
  x = c(0, myCoord$az[ind], myCoord$az[ind], 0)
  y = c(0, 0, 1, 1)
  z = c(0, myCoord$ax[ind], myCoord$ax[ind], 0)
  p <- plot_ly(x = x, y = y, z = z, text = c("M0", "M1", "M2", "M3"),
               type = "mesh3d",
               showscale = FALSE
  ) %>%
    layout(scene=scene, xaxis=bxx,  yaxis=bxx, zaxis=axx )
  print(p)
  Sys.sleep(0.5)
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use latest version of plotly and set axis as atributes of the Scene.

For example:

```
layout.scene = Scene(xaxis=XAxis(title='my x label'),
                     yaxis=YAxis(title='my y label'),
                     zaxis=ZAxis(title='my z label', range=[z_min, z_max]))
```